# $\mathbb{E}[\int_0^TW^2_sdW_s | W_T=c]$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $(W_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ a standard Brownian Motion and let $c\in\mathbb{R}$. How to compute

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^TW^2_sdW_s\mid W_T=c\right]?$$

We thought about rewriting the stochastic integral via Itô's Lemma to find that

$$\int_0^TW^2_sdW_s = \frac{1}{3} W^3_T - \int_0^TW_sds$$

and further

$$\int_0^TW_sds = TW_T-\int_0^TsdW_s.$$

This didn't lead to anything better. Does one a have to construct a markov kernel instead?

Comment: In your first equation $\int_0^T W_s^2 dW_s = \frac 13 W_T^3 - \int_0^T W_s ds$, you can compute $\mathbb{E}[\int_0^T W_s ds | W_T = c]$ by exchanging the order of integration and conditional expectation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Intuitively, I thought about it. But how to deal with
$\mathbb{E}[W_s\mid W_T=c]$?
Is there somehow a way of working with densities of the regular conditional probabilites or is there some kind of time-reversion of the integral possible?

Comment: To compute $\mathbb{E}[W_s | W_T]$, find a constant $c$ such hat $W_s - c W_T$ is independent of $W_T$ (use that independence is equivalent to being uncorrelated for jointly Gaussian random variables).  Then compute $\mathbb{E}[W_s|W_t] = \mathbb{E}[W_s - c W_T + c W_T | W_t] = \mathbb{E}[W_s - c W_T] + c W_T = c W_T$.